# `JS` логика слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

`JS` логика слайдера.

После нажатия на indicator переменная "i" обнуляется, а должна продолжаться с того же места. Почему не работает как задумано?

Более подробно и на примере по ссылке на [песочницу](https://codepen.io/pursam/pen/QWVbBba).
Cмотреть в консоль на изменение "i"

```
let indicators = document.querySelector('.indicators');

let i = 0;
let interval = 1000;
let slidesCount = 5 // по умолчанию

function slider() {
  i = (i + 1 + slidesCount) % slidesCount;
  console.log(`next ${i}`);
}

setInterval(slider, interval);

indicators.addEventListener('click', function (element) {
  if (element.target) {
    let number = element.target.getAttribute('data-slide-to');
    if (i != number) {
      i = number
      console.log(`indicator ${i}`);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Зачем вы в качестве **i** берете остаток от деления? Так задумано? И получая данные из getAttribute, вы получаете **строку** (У вас не строгое сравнение, пройдет), но далее вы этот атрибут в индикаторе не меняете нигде, поэтому там лежит какое то значение, заданное по умолчанию. Полагаю, что после нажатия, вы в интервале получаете строку, берете остаток от деления это 0. Вот и сброс

Comment: Постарайся сделать работающий пример прямо тут.

Comment: Действительно в number записывалась строка. Вылечил добавив parseInt 
```let number = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-slide-to'));```
И всё стало работать как и было задумано. В общем ошибка была в типизации переменных и взаимодействиях с ними. Весьма благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Вылечил обернув значение переменной в parseInt

```
let number = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-slide-to'));
```

И всё стало работать как и было задумано. В общем ошибка была в типизации переменных и взаимодействиях с ними.